# How to set staggeredGridLayout RecyclerView for Multi Layout?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I try staggeredGridLayout RecyclerView to create grid.
with code :

```
//for global layout    
mLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2,StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
```

I have problem how the way, if I set Like :

- layout : 2 Grid
- layout Landscape (rotated): 3 Grid
- layout large: 3 Grid
- layout large Landscape (rotated): 4 Grid
- layout xlarge: 4 Grid
- layout xlarge Landscape (rotated): 6 Grid

so how to this ? sorry for my ENglish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create some resource file under your `values` folder, say `config.xml`. Put there an `integer` value that will indicate how many columns you want to see in your `RecyclerView`.

Override this value in other folders, e.g. under `values` you will have

```
<integer name="columns">2</integer>
```

and under `values-land` you will have

```
<integer name="columns">3</integer>
```

Then you can use this in runtime this way: `getResources().getInteger(R.integer.columns)`